# I've developed C# AddIn for Excel VSTO 2013, but it works only on my machine

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2013, excel-addins

I've developed an AddIn for Excel using C# and install it on my machine it works well on my machine only but when I retry to install it on different machines it not working anymore.

Comment: Why not working?, You have a exception   trace?

Comment: I create a setup project and after installing MSI on a different machine I don't find the add-ins listed in Excel as on my machine.

Comment: But, can you install?, If the instalation as seccesful, go to excel options, then to complements, then on combobox select com complements and your complement apear on the menú after press the button next to combobox

Comment: @henocsalinas means Add-ins / COM Add-ins... It sounds like you add-in may not be correctly *registered* in Windows. For it to load automatically it must be registered. Have you read about installing in the VSTO documentation on MSDN?

Comment: Yes, ir you install as a click once intallall project you need a clicnonce certificate, then regoster a certificate on cliente PC, and install the add in inwork with this type projects of excel addin, i generare a certificate and install as security instance of certidicate on cliente PC,